# Recursion adding up numbers

Tags: recursion

I am very bad at recursion and I am trying to get to learn it. I have this function

```
public static int ques07(int n) {
        int sum = 1;
        int k = 1;
        while (sum <= n) {
            sum = sum + k;
            k++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I am trying to write a recursive equivalent of this function, I have achieved this so far

```
 public static int ques7(int n) {

        int sum = 1;

       if(sum <= n)
        return sum + ques7(n-1);
        else
            return sum;

    }
```

But I suspect this is not right, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int recSum(int n, int sum, int k) {
    if ((sum+k)<=n){
        return recSum(n,sum+k, k+1);
    }else{
        return (sum+k);
    }
}
```

To check, whether functions are the same, you can write:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Original sum ";
  std::cout << ques07(22)<<"\n";
  std::cout << "Recursive sum ";
  std::cout << recSum(22,1,1);  

}
```

But remember, recursion is more memory consuming. Using WHILE cycle, you are limited only with INT variable. Using recursion you are limited with INT parameters AND stack memory (more memory used every time new function is called).